# How can I upload an icon for my app on facebook with out the black grainy borders?

Tags: facebook, graphics, icons

I have a logo and when I upload it to facebook it has a black border around it. I think this is because it has a transparent background and has a shadow. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: This question is out of context in stack overflow as far as I know..

Comment: This is still a valid question for developers looking to ensure quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook doesn't support transparent images and coverts everything to a JPG file.  Save your file as a JPG (using an appropriate background color) and then try to upload it.

Comment: What color background should I use?

Comment: Start with white.  Open it up in Photoshop or other photo editor, or have a designer help you out real quick.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly, but it will apply a near all white background to your icon.

---

**In Sketch:**

1. Add a white (`#ffffff`) background filled layer to your design
2. Set the `Height` and `Width` of the layer to `1023.5`
3. Position the layer on the `X` and `Y` at `0.5`

[image]

*This will bypass facebook's transparency limitation, and the space around the image is so small you can't see the border that facebook applies to the image.*

---

**Result**

[image]